# ASP.NET MVC controller to either return error or model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionresult

I have an ASP.NET MVC action that returns a model to the user.

But if the data is not found I want to return NotFound. ASP.NET MVC doesn't like it since the return type is of that model.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: The standard practice is to return [NotFound()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.notfound)

Answer (score 2):

```
public ActionResult GetModel(int id)
{
    // Retrieve the model from your data source
    var model = GetDataFromSource(id);

    if (model == null)
    {
        // If the model is not found, return a NotFound response
        return NotFound();
    }

    // If the model is found, return it as a ViewResult or any other appropriate action result type
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: This is an issue for me. I am returning  Task<CompanyTemplateV1Model> and I cannot change that to ActionResult.

Comment: @user1094183 - Jeremy Stevens is exactly right (I "upvoted" his reply.  Once your problem's resolved, I encourage you to "upvote" and "accept" it).  Q: Can you [Edit] your post and show us your code?  And copy/paste the exact error you're getting?

Comment: you can't return notFound in your case if your return value is of an unresolved task.  You need to change it to an ActionResult.

Comment: @John Lord: You're absolutely correct.  Which is why it would be nice if the OP showed some code.  There are several good alternatives.  One of them is to make the call synchronous (like Jeremy Stevens's example).

Comment: i think i left out some words while typing.  I meant to say "unresolved task of your model".    This is perfectly legal:  Public Task<ActionResult> and it do it myself.

Answer (score -1):

You could build an exception handler and set that as middleware to convert a specific exception to a 404 response, then just throw that exception from your code (or have the middleware catch an exception that may be thrown anyway).

Exception handler would look like this:

```
public class ExceptionHandler : IMiddleware
{
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        try
        {
            await next(context);
        }
        catch (KeyNotFoundException e) // Or whatever exception you want to use
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(e.Message); // Or nothing, whatever
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it as part of the request pipeline like

```
app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandler>();
```

Then whenever you throw that exception, it will be returned to the caller as a 404.

Edit: What's with the downvotes at least tell me why

Comment: I'm not going to downvote it but you are returning a 404 error to indicate a record isn't found.  That's not what 404 errors are for.  They are to indicate missing resources.

Comment: So I should have told the OP "don't return a 404 here, your goal is invalid so I won't answer your question" instead? They explicitly want to return NotFound when the record isn't found. I don't know the background, so possibly all this call does is indeed get that record, so if the record doesn't exist, 404 makes sense, doesn't it?

Comment: no it doesn't.  404 is designated as representing a missing endpoint, either from the webpage (or endpoint) being missing entirely, or out of service for some reason, or you've entered an invalid url.  A server can purposefully throw a NotFound (which specifically creates a 404 error) when it's online but you've went to a non-existent file or controller method.  In this case, You would want to return a 200 with an error message in the body.    Not blaming you though.  The OP is attempting to do that exact thing even though it violates web standards (hence no downvote).